# Stratis filesystem will not mount after a reboot because the disk is full

Tags: redhat, mount, compression, nextcloud, thin-provisioning

It concerns a rhel8 server that has two disks (sda and sdb), and only on the sdb disk a Stratis filesystem has been created. After a restart of the server, no more mount point appears on the sdb disk. When I try to mount it I get the following error.

```
# mount -a                                                                          
mount: /var/www/html/nextcloud/data: mount(2) system call failed: No space left on device.
```

Below is some additional information:

```
# stratis pool list
Name                     Total Physical   Properties
data   102 GiB / 101.92 GiB / 83.15 MiB      ~Ca,~Cr
```

And some information from the kernel ring buffer.

```
# dmesg

device-mapper: thin: 253:9: reached low water mark for data device: sending event.
device-mapper: thin: 253:9: switching pool to out-of-data-space (error IO) mode
XFS (dm-11): metadata I/O error in "xlog_recover_iodone+0x49/0x80 [xfs]" at daddr 0x3819afc0 len 32 error 28
XFS (dm-11): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x1) called from line 298 of file fs/xfs/xfs_log_recover.c. Return address = 0000000055731d26
XFS (dm-11): I/O Error Detected. Shutting down filesystem
XFS (dm-11): Please unmount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)
XFS (dm-11): log mount/recovery failed: error -28
XFS (dm-11): log mount failed
device-mapper: thin: 253:9: switching pool to write mode
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
XFS (dm-11): Mounting V5 Filesystem
XFS (dm-11): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
device-mapper: thin: 253:9: reached low water mark for data device: sending event.
device-mapper: thin: 253:9: switching pool to out-of-data-space (error IO) mode
XFS (dm-11): metadata I/O error in "xlog_recover_iodone+0x49/0x80 [xfs]" at daddr 0x3819afc0 len 32 error 28
XFS (dm-11): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x1) called from line 298 of file fs/xfs/xfs_log_recover.c. Return address = 0000000055731d26
XFS (dm-11): I/O Error Detected. Shutting down filesystem
XFS (dm-11): Please unmount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)
XFS (dm-11): log mount/recovery failed: error -28
XFS (dm-11): log mount failed
device-mapper: thin: 253:9: switching pool to write mode
```

And an overview of the fstab file.

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sun Aug 22 09:36:35 2021
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=534d9680-7334-4de1-9fed-310406a63899 /boot xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp  /tmp                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var  /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-var_tmp /var/tmp             xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/rootvg-swap none                    swap    defaults        0 0
UUID=97cbbfba-37e3-46f8-b245-8b4306f28174 /var/www/html/nextcloud/data  xfs defaults,x-systemd.requires=stratisd.service 0 0
```

Hopefully someone can help me further?

Answer (score 0):

It think, there is with partition.
As I have checked. firstly destroyed file and pool
then create new partition and check.
It is working for me.